# IE11, slice and outerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

chrome and firefox can show like `<p><span>xxxx</span></p>`, but IE11 show like `<p></p>` when use 'slice' to cut HTMLObject Array,how to get answer ?

javascript:

```
var wrap = document.querySelector('.wrap');
var select = document.querySelector('.select');
var marks = Array.prototype.slice.call(wrap.querySelectorAll('p'));
var impression_num = document.querySelector('#impression_num');
impression_num.textContent = marks.length;
wrap.innerHTML = ''; // I think problem start here

var ul = document.createElement('ul');
var start = 0;
var length = 20;
var num = Math.ceil(marks.length / 20);
var selectData = marks.slice(start, length);

console.log(selectData[0].outerHTML); // show <p></p> not <p><span>xxxx</span></p>
```

HTML:

```
<section class="wrap">
  <p><span>xxxx</span></p>
  <p>xxxx<span id="impression_num"></span>xxxx</p>
  <p class="impression" style="font-size:22px;" ><a href="#">xxxx</a></p>
  <p class="impression">xxxx</p>
  <p class="impression">xxxx</p>
  <p class="impression">xxxx</p>
<selection>
```

Comment: does it log correctly if you comment out the innerHTML clearing?

Comment: when put `wrap.innerHTML=''` behind console.log(..), it can work. Why only IE11 have this problem LOL

Comment: i would imagine it handles orphan nodes differently. i'm not sure the spec covers the behavior or if ie11 is broken. can you wait until after the problematic code to clear the container?

Comment: it can work and show right tags if clear container after console.log(), i see console have a `DOM7011:error`, maybe problem connect it.